# How to restore VS 2015 extensions in VS 2017?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-extensions, visual-studio-2017

I would like to know what it takes to restore Visual Studio 2015 extensions in Visual Studio 2017. Does it happen automatically or requires some configuration. As I am planning to upgrade existing Visual Studio 2015 application in Visual Studio 2017, any suggestion or link to any appropriate documentation would be appreciable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean you want to upgrade your visual studio 2015 extension to visual studio 2017 extension?

Comment: Yes @ColeWu-MSFT

Answer (score 0):

1. Install Visual Studio 2017 with required workloads
2. Open VSIX Solution in Visual Studio 2017
3. Update the Microsoft.VSSDK.BuildTools NuGet package
4. Make changes to the VSIX extension manifest
5. Update Debug settings for project
6. Check that the extension builds correctly (as a VSIX v3)
7. Check when all required prerequisites are installed
8. Check when missing the required prerequisites

For more information, please refer to:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/how-to-migrate-extensibility-projects-to-visual-studio-2017

Comment: Hi @ColeWu-MSFT, thanks for your time. I'll try these steps and will let you know if there will be any concern. Will mark it as answer thereafter. :)

Answer (score 0):

At very least you need to do the following:

1- Update installation target in the vsixmanifest file:

```
<InstallationTarget Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community" Version="[14.0, 15.0]" />
```

2- Add prerequisites to the vsixmanifest file:

```
<Prerequisites>
    <Prerequisite Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CoreEditor" Version="[15.0.25904.2,16.0)" DisplayName="Visual Studio core editor" />
</Prerequisites>
```

3- Build using Visual Studio 2017 (you will need some modifications in csproj file related to the ToolsVersion but Visual Studio 2017 is going to do it for you).

Those are the minimum steps for migrating your extension to VS 2017.

Everything is explained in the following link:

http://www.visualstudioextensibility.com/2017/01/10/its-time-to-change-the-vsix-manifest-of-your-extension-to-v3-for-visual-studio-2017-compatibility/